# Google My Business API always return Invalid Requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-my-business-api, google-api-ruby-client

I'm building an app that ***get all the google reviews from the connected user***.

I want to use Google My Business API for that.

I have made all the prerequisites Google asked for, and I have activated the API in my project, as well as asked the user for the authorizations.

The Google My Business API being private, I couldn't find the gem for it on https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-ruby-client

So, following the steps described in [this GitHub Issue](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-ruby-client/issues/662), I generated the API in my project form this [Discovery File](https://developers.google.com/static/my-business/samples/mybusiness_google_rest_v4p9.json).

The generated API is in my rails project in `lib/google-apis-mybusiness_v4`

In my Gemfile:

```
gem "google-apis-mybusiness_v4", path: "lib/google-apis-mybusiness_v4"
```

the code I tried (the user is connected successfully):

```
require "google/apis/mybusiness_v4"

#...
secrets = Google::APIClient::ClientSecrets.load("./code_secret_client.json")
authorizer = secrets.to_authorization
authorizer.update!(scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage", access_token: user.token )

service = Google::Apis::MybusinessV4::MyBusinessService.new
service.authorization = authorizer

service.list_accounts #=> Google::Apis::ClientError: Invalid request
```

I showed `list_account` here but any function of MyBusinessService returns `Google::Apis::ClientError: Invalid request`

I also tried tu use some other google APIs, but fetching the gems from ruby-gem, and it works with the same code

Example:

```
#Gemfile
gem 'google-apis-mybusinessaccountmanagement_v1', '~> 0.1'

#code
require "google/apis/mybusinessaccountmanagement_v1"

secrets = Google::APIClient::ClientSecrets.load("./code_secret_client.json")
authorizer = secrets.to_authorization
authorizer.update!(scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage", access_token: user.token )

service_management = Google::Apis::MybusinessaccountmanagementV1::MyBusinessAccountManagementService.new
service_management.authorization = authorizer

service_management.list_accounts(options: { authorization: authorizer }) #=> successfully lists all the accounts
```

(I don't know why I have to specify the authorization again in the options, but it only works that way. Also I tried `service.list_accounts(options: { authorization: authorizer })` with the MyBusinessService list_accounts as well, same error, `Google::Apis::ClientError: Invalid request` )

This is the first time I've used a gem this way, so maybe I made mistakes that would explain the error I'm getting.